# Make Apache NOT listen on port 443 for some domains

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, mod-rewrite, lets-encrypt

I have an Apache server set up to listen on port 80 for a few domains and 443 on two of them (at least that's what I'd want).
So I have my Virtualhost *:443 with "my-ssl-domain.com" and "my-other-ssl-domain.com" ServerName. Both domains also have a Virtualhost *:80 that simply redirects to the HTTPS version using mod_rewrite. I'm using let's encrypt for both of them.

I also have multiple (>10) other domains that should only work via HTTP.

What happens is that if I go to "https://www.my-non-ssl-domain.com" browsers complain that there's no valid certificate. Google seems to also index that page and I'd like to avoid it as it seems to be bad SEO.

I'd like it to 301 redirect "https://www.my-non-ssl-domain.com" to "http://www.my-non-ssl-domain.com" or at least not answer at all, as if the domain with HTTPS simply did not exist.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don’t use `Virtualhost *:443` then, but specify a host name explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean? I failed to mention that Apache listens on the same IP address for all my domains (SSL and non-SSL).

Comment: If you use `*:443`, then this VirtualHost will be used as the fallback for all host names that do not have their “own” VH explicitly specified. So you need to use something like `Virtualhost somedomain.local:443` to indicate that this VH is only for that specific domain (plus ServerAliases), but not for every incoming HTTPS request for which no explicit configuration exists.

Comment: That will not help. If no matching ServerName is found, Apache will still answer with default VirtualHost configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to respond (without warning) to `https://` request without the correct certificate, that is just how the protocol works.
There are several options, but none of them might be optimal for you:

1. Have two public IP addresses, use one for the sites with both `http`+`https`, and the other for `http` only. Then configure Apache to listen on port 443 only for the first one.
2. Let's encrypt certs cost (almost) nothing, so just go and get certs for all domain names (even if you for some reason don't want to serve content over `https`, at least you will be able to properly redirect visitors to `http` site)
3. I am not aware of the SEO consequences, but if you configure default `<VirtualHost *:443>` like this (you need to place it so that is the first VirtualHost :443 loaded by Apache, it is best to put it at the bottom of `httpd.conf`):

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:443>
> ServerName non.existing_host.noTld
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

In that case, the clients will not get Certificate mismatch warning (`NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`), they will be disonnected due to SSL protocol error (`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`) which may or may not be better for SEO, I really don't know.

Comment: I just set up two more IP addresses, for my two SSL domains. I will listen on 443 only on those domains, so it should be fixed. Thank you.